# PHP cURL getting plaintext

Tags: php, curl, plaintext

I'm using cURL in PHP to get webpage content and it's working great. But my program now requires me to get only plain-text from the target site, instead of HTML. I've looked extensively for this but no one seems to have the answer.  I've also tried setting `CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT=1` in my cURL options, but this seems to have no effect on the results.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the following:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

The return value of `curl_exec` should then be the data.

Comment: This is what I currently do to get the data. I want just plain text though. Not HTML as this provides

Comment: @Alan: If you don't want the HTML tags to be rendered when printing it out to your page, use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities). If you don't want the HTML tags period, then use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is what you are looking for:

```
<?
$address = file_get_contents('http://www.thesite.com/file.html');
echo $address;



$file = file_get_contents('./file.txt', true);

 or 

$file = file_get_contents('./file.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

?>
```

Comment: not plain, but the whole page --> $address = file_get_contents('http://php.net/');

Comment: I think is not possible to separate the whole file only in text format, cause it will return no formatted content, and will mess everything up... If you want to return a text file, it is better you read a  xml file or even a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I do like this to get the content of another page.

```
<?php
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
    {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        $contents = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        if ($contents) return $contents;
            else return FALSE;
    }


echo curl_get_file_contents("http://www.php.net");
?>
```

But it returns to me the whole content.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you  want to strip off all the HTML tags on the page?

Simply use the [`strip_tags()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).